# Share forms authentication between existing Web Forms and new MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms, forms-authentication, asp.net-identity-2

I have an existing ASP.NET 4.5 Web forms application. We have secured it with cookie based Forms Authentication. I am working on a new MVC application which will run on the same server but as a different project. New application will be a different sub-domain so cookies can be shared. So I want to secure the MVC application. I have 2 options:

1. Secure MVC application by sharing Forms Authentication. This doesn't work for me. FYI, I am using same machine and validation keys in both web.config.
2. We want to migrate to MVC ultimately so is there a way to secure MVC with new Identity or something and modify the Web Forms to authenticate using the new approach?

Need to implement the solution within a week. Please Help!!!